# Highlighting brackets while using regex

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

Say I have a script like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,"< file.txt") or die;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {

        if ($line =~ /^\s*[^}]/){
                print "hey $line\n";
        }
}
```

The brackets are matching and the script runs just alright. Still, the automatic highlighting of Vim (version 7.2) gets corrupted by the regex pattern including a bracket. I would like to swap between matching brackets by pressing `%` but can't use it anymore. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As a general-purpose text editor, Vim can deal with escaped braces (cp. `:help cpo-M`), but as it doesn't know the full underlying syntax, this has its limits, especially with complex languages like Perl and C++. So, there's litte you can do, except rewriting the offending part, or switching to another editor / IDE with a full parser for Perl.

<sup>PS: Vim 7.2 is from 2008 and *quite* outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.4; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from the [Cream project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/)), it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.</sup>